# Hiding searchable content in a PDF

Tags: xetex, pdf

Is there a way to have searchable hidden text in a PDF using LaTeX? For example, is it possible to embed an ID that is searchable, but not visible?

Answer (score 19):

With the `accsupp` package, "Nothing to see here" shows in your document, but "Hidden message" is searchable.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{accsupp,lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\BeginAccSupp{method=escape,ActualText=Hidden message}%
    Nothing to see here.
\EndAccSupp{}%
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

The searchable content of the document is this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.
Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus
et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra
metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices. Phasellus
eu tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium
quis, viverra ac, nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum. Aenean
faucibus. Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla. Cura-
bitur auctor semper nulla. Donec varius orci eget risus. Duis nibh mi, congue
eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci sit amet orci dignissim
rutrum.
Hidden message Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollici-
tudin vel, wisi. Morbi auctor lorem non justo. Nam lacus libero, pretium at,
lobortis vitae, ultricies et, tellus. Donec aliquet, tortor sed accumsan biben-
dum, erat ligula aliquet magna, vitae ornare odio metus a mi. Morbi ac orci
et nisl hendrerit mollis. Suspendisse ut massa. Cras nec ante. Pellentesque a
nulla. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur
ridiculus mus. Aliquam tincidunt urna. Nulla ullamcorper vestibulum turpis.
Pellentesque cursus luctus mauris.
```

Answer (score 15):

Without additional package, by setting the text rendering mode to `3` (neither stroked nor filled):

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
Hidden text follows, but you won't see it. \makebox[0pt][l]{\pdfliteral page {q 3 Tr}ID:3.1415\pdfliteral page {Q}}This comes after.
\end{document}
```

---

Just saw the `{xetex}` tag. So the code below will work with any of `pdflatex`, `lualatex`, `xelatex`.

Moreover, unlike Evince, Acrobat Reader seems to scramble the hidden text with the overlaid text, making it unsearchable eventually. To fix this, we scale down the hidden text by 100000 and move it to the right, off page. This also keeps the hidden text from becoming visible if we select the normal text with the mouse:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pdfbase}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand\hiddenText[1]{
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\hspace{\paperwidth}\pbs_literal:nn{page}{q~0.00001~0~0~0.00001~0~0~cm~3~Tr}#1\pbs_literal:nn{page}{Q}}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
Hidden text follows, but you won't see it.\hiddenText{ID:3.1415} This comes after.
\end{document}
```